# How do I get the title of an uploaded image which is to be entered as a value in the image ID column in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, image-uploading, pass-by-value

[Click to see the upload option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vro93.png)When I choose an image file, it gets chosen but I am unable to extract the title of the chosen image. I need to get this title and push it to a table as a part of a column. Is there any way to do the same? [Click to see the table fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaSV1.png)

[The code sample here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Fam.png)

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample?

Comment: Duly added. Kindly check and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but you can extract the title through onChange like this.

```
<input
  type="file"
  onChange={x => {
    console.log(x.target.files[0].name);
  }}
/>
```

here's the sandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-0uemf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: This throws an error saying 'Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.'

Comment: Moreover, what I need to do is pass the title to a table. How do I do that?

Comment: Here. I updated the sandbox sample to pass the values to table as well as removed the error.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-ohpzy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you so much!